# Listbox causing a separate postback for the textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, listbox, autopostback

Step to replicate the problem

First, type in text in the textbox but do not type enter.
Then, select a different index in the listbox.
Finally, view that both ID ( listbox and textbox ) will show up at the eventtarget.

expected result
Only one ID will show up at the eventtarget, which is the one that initialize it = listbox onselected index change.

Here's the code:

`<TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
<ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" onselectedindexchanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Text="0" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</ListBox>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
if (IsPostBack)
{
string target = Request["__EVENTTARGET"] as string;
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("__EVENTTARGET: " + target);
}
}
protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}`

Answer (score 0):

If your text box has its `AutoPostBack` property set to `true`, the text box will cause a PostBack when it loses focus. This is by design. [See the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autopostback.aspx).

Therefore, you getting the ID of the text box there is actually the expected behavior. If you don't want that, consider not setting the text box `AutoPostBack` property to `true`.